# Python 3 project into exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, cx-freeze

I've made my first Python program, using Python 3.2. Now I'm trying to figure out how to make it an executable.

I pretty much only need it for Windows only. I've searched as much as possible and found out that `py2exe` doesn't support Python 3. `cxfreeze` does, but I can't figure out how to make a single executable of my program with it. I need it as a portable one-file exe.

Please bear with me as I am a total newcomer :) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd have to use `cx_freeze` along with some tool like VMWare ThinApp to package Python and your executable together in one executable.

Comment: I used cx_Freeze, then bundled the files into an installer using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It doesn't make a *portable* exe, because you have to install it, but it's quite simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cxfreeze` to make the executable (and other files it creates), compress them into a *.7z archive using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), then use [7-ZIP SFX Maker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sfx-maker/) to turn it into a self extracting archive.

When creating the SFX archive, configure it so that the main executable `cxfreeze` generates runs when the files are extracted. You can also change the archives icon, as well as tell the archive to extract and run from a temporary folder.

When the user runs the exe, the files will extract to the temporary folder and the program will run. To the user, it will behave exactly like a normal exe file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python docs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/), the only program that will package Python3 as an .exe in `cx_freeze`, and the `cx_freeze` developer has explicitly stated that he will not support single-file executables (due to the 'dirty hacks' needed, which some anti-malware programs flag as malware).

Comment on the [feature request to add Python3 support to py2exe](http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/feature-requests/20/).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare py2exe folder structure with new python3, and make similar. Then you could use [SFX](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) idea to store these folders like libraries, python script and interpreter and set script for SFX to just launch your application. As I remember, this is possible in WinRar, and as I think now, in other archivers.