# Building a Windows executable from python source

Tags: python, windows

We have a Py module we'd like to give to users in the form of a windows executable. Is there a good tried and true tool to package a py module to Windows exe?

Comment: @mgilson you should make that an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Note that there aren't solutions that will compile Python in to opaque byte or machine code, really, only tools that will give you the ability to distribute a 1-click-runnable Python program.

Comment: @mgilson we did, but it currently depends on/built for py2.6 our dev environment is set for py 2.7

Comment: @sr2222 that's exactly what we're looking for. Not looking for a compiler but rather for a "standalone" executable for machines w/o py.

Comment: @Duncan -- I didn't feel confident enough to make it an answer as I've never used py2exe myself.  I've just seen it referenced a bunch of times.

Comment: @Syrahn Good, just wanted to make sure you were aware, as lots of people are looking for ways to obscure the code of distributables when they ask questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `py2exe` if you're running a 3.x version of Python, you can use `cx_freeze` (http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't package the program into a single executable, but you can package all the files it generates into a self-extracting archive for deployment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511735/369977 for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Python extention [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

In Python you can use the code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

to make the executable test.exe

Comment: Aye, I was few secs to late. I see we Googled the same code :)

Comment: I just stole the tutorial directly from their website

Comment: likewise here. I don't understand why @Syrahn didn't Google it before asking. It was the first thing that popped up on the serach.

Comment: @Gunnar I did Google it before asking. Don't jump to conclusions. Firstly the project seems to have been abandoned since 2008, secondly it's only compatible with Py 2.6

Comment: @Syrahn, really?  There is a py2exe package for Python 2.7 in [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe/download).

Comment: @Raceyman yeah we tried that, but it wont work with 2.7 64-bit. We're looking into either switching to 32-bit version or see if there's another alternative. The 64-bit version issue seems to be a python windows installer bug.

Comment: @Syrahn There is a [64 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe/download) version for 2.7 there as well, have you tried that?

Comment: @Raceyman Yup. It's apparently a bug of python (itself) installer for windows that's not setting the right flags in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

So long as you have [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) installed it will compile `hello.py` to an exe, (it actually just bundles the stdlib and interpreter into an executable.)